# Flutter How to display several values in a subtitle?

Tags: flutter, subtitle

I am trying to display the two values in the subtitle but I can't because there is only the text of the code which is displayed which is normal for the moment you will tell me
Thank you for your help

```
   Divider(color: Colors.black),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Product details'),
        subtitle: Text('widget.Finalprodcut_detials.toString() \nwidget.Finalprodcut_test.toString()'),
      ),
      Divider(color: Colors.black),
```

Comment: I don't get your problem, what do you mean by several values?

Answer (score 4):

You can assign column to subtitle property and in column put two text widget will solve your issue.

Following code demonstrates how to do.

```
  subtitle: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('${widget.Finalprodcut_detials.toString()}'),
                  Text('${widget.Finalprodcut_test.toString()}')
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Glad to hear that it wotk for you. Accept my answer if it is.